# Compactness of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an infinite space, I thought it is never compact no matter what metric it is endowed with. But, so what is the point in checking for non compactness of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with different metrics, does it not derive directly from the definition of the space?

Comment: An infinite space can be compact when equipped with a suitable metric.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Can you give me an example of an infinite set that is compact?

Comment: @Alessandro $[0,1]$, usual topology.

Comment: @Alessandro What you probably mean is *unbounded*, not infinite. And if so, you are right: no unbounded space is compact. But $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be bounded with some suitable metric, so you can't apply this reasoning.

Comment: Compactness is a topological property. If the topology is fixed then the space is compact or is not compact. Metrics that induce this topology do not play a part in this.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Ok I got the point. So in the case of finite sets, it is not the finiteness that allow me to state that are compact in any metric space but the fact that they are bounded, right?

Comment: @Alessandro No. Finite implies compact. The converse isn't true.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Ok now it's clear. Thank you!

Comment: Let $f:\Bbb R^n\to[0,1]$ be a bijection (Cantor showed that such a bijection always exists). Define a metric $d$ on $\Bbb R^n$ by $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$. Then $\Bbb R^n$ is compact under this metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of compactness depends on the topology of the space.

For a finite dimensional space all the p-norms are [strongly equivalent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics), this includes the Euclidean metric, the taxicab distance, ... So the space is not compact with any of these metrics.

Maybe considering a weird metric (possibly one that does not come from a norm) would give you the desired result, but $\mathbb{R}^n$ won't be compact with any of the usual metrics.

Comment: So I can state that unbounded sets are never compact, whereas bounded sets can be compact even if infinite?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ you can, @Alessandro; there is a theorem ensuring that a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is compact iff the subspace is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and bounded.

Comment: @GudsonChou Yes, I know Heine-Borel theorem. But can you apply it also to infinite subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Checking a proof of the theorem and seeing if it uses finiteness assumption can be helpful for you. :) @Alessandro

Comment: @Alessandro Sure, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a complete metric space, so a set is compact if and only if it's closed and bounded